# Visiting USA from Mexico as a UK citizen

Tags: usa, uk-citizens, mexico

Could you tell me what documentation I would need to visit Las Vegas if I'm a UK citizen currently working in Mexico City?

Comment: The documentation you require differs depending on your means of transportation and on the purpose of your visit.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you're flying, and that you're visiting for tourism or business, you need valid ESTA authorization and the passport to which your valid ESTA authorization is tied.

You may also be asked to show evidence of your immigration status in Mexico, but of course you'll have that with you because you'll need it on the return journey.  There are two reasons for this, but one applies only to subsequent visits.  The first reason is that an air ticket from the US to Mexico only satisfies the statutory "round-trip ticket" requirement if you reside in Mexico.  The second is that on subsequent visits you may have to show that you reside in Mexico because that exempts you from the rule that time in Mexico does not reset the 90-day period of admission under the VWP.

If you're crossing the border by land, you don't need the ESTA authorization.  If your visit is for reasons other than business or pleasure, you'll need a visa of the appropriate category.

Comment: does the above apply if I've only worked in Mexico for 18 months, have not immigrated there and do not intend to settle there in the future

Comment: @MOIRAHUGHES yes.  You just need to show that you're living in Mexico, not that you've moved there permanently.  A New Zealander here who lives in Mexico says that he got a visa to make frequent trips to more smoothly, but his initial visits were indeed under the visa waiver program.

Comment: @MOIRAHUGHES How are you working in Mexico if you haven't immigrated?  Do you have a work permit?  That normally requires residency.  Did you travel via the USA to get to Mexico originally?  (Although that's probably not an issue if it was 18 months ago)